Should laundry equipment be internally braced for long-distance travel?
We are moving from New Zealand to Australia.  We have Miele Washing Machine and Dryer.  When you buy these appliances, they come with bits to stop movement during transportation.  I haven't kept them.  Or, I have kept them but I don't know what they look like. They will be going on a ship across an ocean which will induce a lot of movement and jerks.
Qs:  Is it necessary to brace the innards of either appliance for such a travel?

Sell, move without, buy is almost always more efficient than moving large appliances. Surely you can contact Miele and get replacement shipping parts if yours are lost, however.

Also consider that the warranty may not be offered in another country, selling and re-buying may be a better option for you.   Or stuff every accessible hole with linen/towels/to save space and eliminate movement.

@Ecnerwal, I have contacted them, but have not heard back yet.

@Criggie, we are actually building a new house where the builder is going to supply all appliances,  The ones we are taking will serve use for another year before we sell them in Australia.  The 2nd hand market in NZ is rubbish.  I would rather dump them then give them  away for peanuts.  We are paying for a 40ft container anyway, so shipping wont cost ay more.

If loading the machines into a personal-sized truck or van with comfortable suspension and driving with reasonable care those parts are somewhat optional.
Put the machines on a commercial freight truck (not a comfortable suspension)  and especially into an ocean going vessel and that's why those parts were installed at the factory - the internal parts of the machine will beat themselves to death during the trip.
What they look like should be revealed in the owner's or installation manual where they are removed during installation.

Yep. Most washers have heavy cast cement ballast for stability. At even a few Gs of load they can wreak havoc on their mounts and nearby parts, or even compromise the cabinet.

The owners manual (that we had anyway) had no information on removing them.  If they had, we could have reversed the instructions.
From my Googling, I was expecting restraining bars on both the Washer and the Dryer.  Support finally responded with pictures of a pair.  Again, I assumed that it was one each.
But it turns out that only the washer needs them and has two of the.  They are stored in the back of the unit.  Picture below -


What is the scale of those bars (approximate length & diameter)?
